Extract a PDF Layout to Image without chaging lineweight in python
I'm working on a project where I need to extract images from a PDF layout that was originally exported from AutoCAD. The layout contains detailed drawings, specifically of solar modules, and I need these images in either PNG or JPG format. Every time I try it, the polygons, in this case representing solar modules, changes or set its lineweight.
I have try several ways and libraries (PyMuPDF, OpenCV, PIL, Pdf2image). Despite trying different approaches and libraries, I haven't found a solution that maintains the original appearance of the lineweights as they are in the AutoCAD-exported PDF.
You can download the PDF from this link: https://mega.nz/file/sx9XlSCQ#8Rj0qW5phaKkExvznX-RFGd4ySj4bp4kGOg6ZVF9aYU
This is the result I'm getting: (Tiny lineweight)

This is the expected result: (Strong lineweight)

My question is:
Is there a method or specific library that can accurately extract images from PDF layouts exported from AutoCAD while preserving the original appearance of the elements? Alternatively, is there a known workaround for this specific issue?

Try export from pdf to png (set 600 dpi) and use cv2.erode()

As Alex Alex recommended, tried "pdf to png (set 600 dpi) and use cv2.erode()". Got slightly better results, but the blue somehow now turns into red. Btw, I used kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)

not an OpenCV problem. -- find out what the line weight in your PDF is. if that is insufficient, either mess with the PDF to change the weight of the lines you want, or find out if your chosen PDF rendering library can do that on the fly, or find a library that can. -- adobe acrobat can "enhance hairlines" or whatever they call it. that'll draw all lines with at least 1.0 pixel width, even if it should appear thinner on the chosen display size.

By the looks of it, the lineweight in the PDF is set to "hairline", because if I zoom in on it in macOS's Preview, they're always 1 px wide. IOW, there is no "original appearance" to retain.

As discussed in the comments, the AutoCAD export has set linewidths for those objects to zero.
Quoting the PDF 1.7 spec, section 8.4.3.2 Line Width, emphasis mine,

A line width of 0 shall denote the thinnest line that can be rendered at device resolution: 1 device pixel wide. However, some devices cannot reproduce 1-pixel lines, and on high-resolution devices, they are nearly invisible. Since the results of rendering such zero-width lines are device-dependent, they should not be used.

There's this Autodesk article on how to fix unexpectedly thin or thick line widths, but let's assume we can't touch those settings.
This pretty hacky script using PyMuPDF's low-level functions tries to patch up the line-width commands to be non-zero – I noticed other objects in the documents used line width 6, so that's what I'm going for here.
import pymupdf
import re

doc = pymupdf.open("Layout.pdf")

xreflen = doc.xref_length()
for xref in range(1, xreflen):
    if stream := doc.xref_stream(xref):
        if isinstance(stream, bytes):
            # Pattern for "set line width to zero" (that hopefully doesn't occur in other contexts)
            new_stream = re.sub(br"\s0 w\s", b" 6 w ", stream)
            if stream != new_stream:
                doc.update_stream(xref, new_stream)

doc.save("Layout_modified.pdf")

When I zoom in in macOS preview in the modified file, the blue panels are no longer always hairline thin, but have some heft to them. Chances are rasterizing that patched-up file would result in a nicer outcome.

This trick worked beautifully! Out of the 11 tests I ran, 8 were successful, which is a great outcome. However, I'm still encountering some issues with a few PDFs. I attempted to print all the patterns I found to identify the problem, but unfortunately, that approach didn't yield the results I was hoping for. Would it be possible to share some of these files with you to explore if there's an alternative solution?

There should be no real problem printing a PDF to PNG whatever the thickness of CAD lines are since they should translate to a "minimal" one pixel wide. The simplest is use GhostScript print to PNG256 to maintain the correct lineweight. However the minimum as recommended in CADD standards is 1.8mm at scale e.g. for A4 or A3 outputs.
When using "default it will usually be ZERO and thus in Adobe PDF be just one pixel wide.

Thus when printing or reprinting to image it will simply be one accurate pixel wide.
gs.lnk -sDEVICE=png256 -o "%cd%\Layout.png" -f "%cd%\Layout.pdf"
That should by default (or depending any other choices) produce a perfectly readable small 32 KB page like this.

If you want the mimimal lines thicker than defined simply programmatically "pre-process" with any PDF commands tool that has a thicken "thinlines" function, such as cpdf.
So setting them thicker to 2 points wide GS will faithfully produce this. One nice thing about -thinlines is it only thickens those that are undersized leaving any thicker lines (such as 6pt) exactly as they were.
cpdf.exe -thinlines 2pt "%cd%\Layout.pdf" -o Temp.pdf

To correct for a draughtsman failing to set pen weight to ISO minimum 1.8mm then for 1:1 use that. -thinlines 5.14pt However that would in this case be far too thick since pixels are scale relative and thus the core usage scale needs increasing / allowing for.

